# How to autostart org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender in a feature based eclipse rcp application?

Tags: osgi, eclipse-rcp, e4, eclipse-gemini

I have an eclipse rcp application that uses gemini blueprint. It has two features and hence a feature based product. Some of our bundles depend on service that where created by the blueprint extender. But actually the blueprint extender is only resolved on startup and not activated. Today we work around this by executing code in bundle activators, that checks if the `org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender` bundle was started and if not it gets started.

Adding the bundle to the .product with a start level of 3 and `autoStart=true` has no effect. I think this is because our product is feature based. Is this correct? What is the best way to autostart the extender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit configuration/config.ini file and add the bundle you want started to the osgi.bundles property. For example:

`osgi.bundles=<existing entries>, org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender@3:start`

Comment: In principle this works (it starts the extender bundle). But it leads to some strange behavior when activating other bundles. The activation  can not complete because some `ClassDefNotFound` exceptions occure. I think I have to digg into this deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the start level to 0 and auto start to true?
There is a suggestion in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012738/add-plugins-with-auto-start-to-eclipse-rcp-application) link.May be it can help you.